# How to run ssh login without sudo password?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm sure this is trivial but my googling has mainly led me to people trying to connect via ssh without a password.

What I am trying to do is setup my ssh connection command to not require my sudo password to run the command, I already have my public key setup so I can connect fine.

I can make it so I dont need it by adding using visudo

```
<username> ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

However I dont want to allow all commands to be run without my sudo password, only specifically the connection to my remote server e.g.

```
sudo ssh -i /home/foo/.ssh/id_rsa bar@123.123.123.123 -p12345
```

How do I modify my sudoers file to not require my sudo password for specifically (or as specifically as possible) the above?

Comment: You can add specific command in your sudoers file to avoid sudo, so that user can execute that specific command only without sudo. for example <username> ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/apt

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command to copy SSH public key to your server (/home/bar/.ssh/authorized_keys)

```
ssh-copy-id -i /home/foo/.ssh/id_rsa.pub bar@123.123.123.123
```

Login to the server and create a file in sudoers.d.

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/<username>
```

With the following content.

```
<username>   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

For old Linux distros add the line to visudo (/etc/sudoers)

```
<username> ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Disable Password Authentication and deny root login.

```
vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config

PermitRootLogin no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Restart SSH service

```
systemctl restart sshd.service
```